# Asp.Net core 3.1 put request failed: Failed to proxy the request to http://weatherforecast/1, because the request to the proxy target failed

Tags: angular, visual-studio, asp.net-core

Got a standard Asp.Net Web core (3.1) Angular Template application. Works fine! Added a put request to the WeatherForecastController (forecasts are in a static List weatherList).
Simplified, the request looks like:

```
 [HttpPut("{id}")]
 public async Task<IActionResult> PutForecastItem(int id, WeatherForecast item)
 {
     if (id != item.Id)
     {
         return BadRequest();
     }

     var org  = weatherList.ElementAt(id);
     org.TemperatureC = item.TemperatureC;

     return NoContent();
 }
```

Calling this method (VS2019 debug) error 500 is generated: Http failure response for https://localhost:44345//weatherforecast/1: 500 OK
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Failed to proxy the request to http://weatherforecast/1, because the request to the proxy target failed.

How to fix this? Thanks for any help!

Comment: You might try to use `[FromBody]WeatherForecast item`

Comment: @MartinStaufcik thanks for your reaction! Unfortunately the [FromBody] it did not help. It must be a simple fix, I guess. What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was caused by an extra forward slash:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(`${this.baseUrl}**/**weatherforecast`)
      .subscribe(result => {
         this.forecasts = result;
      }, error => console.error(error));
}
```

Should be:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.http.get<WeatherForecast[]>(`${this.baseUrl}weatherforecast`)
      .subscribe(result => {
         this.forecasts = result;
      }, error => console.error(error));
}
```